# Using google script to copy a updated folder to another sheet, then deleting the original folder and rename the new one to the old name

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a google script that copy's a sheet to another workbook where the sheet exist, resulting in a folder with a name of 'Copy of ...".  Let call that Sheet 'Original'

1. once done the workbook will have a folder called 'Original' and 'Copy of Original'
2. I use script to delete the 'Original' folder
3. I use script to rename the 'Copy of Original' to 'Original'

Problem is now the newly copied file which has additional folders can not reference the new 'Original' and gives an error.

Please advise as to the order this process should be done.
Thanks
Preston

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are saying because we think of spreadsheets when you say workbooks and spreadsheets don't have folders.  They have sheets which of course is complicated since google has decided to called spreadsheets sheets as well.  I guess they're marketing department doesn't contain any google apps script programmers.

Comment: If you would share the script it would be easier to understand your issue. As Cooper says, there are certain things that don't make sense in your question (probably language issue).

Comment: Cooper, I used workbooks/folders to try to make it clear but her goes in script ease.  I use script to copy a sheet to another sheet resulting in 'Copy..'. (I do this because of all the formatting, formulas, banding, data validation, conditional formatting).  Then to clean up, I delete the original sheet, name 'Copy..' sheet to the original name.  The problem now is that other sheets in the spreadsheet can not reference/find then newly created sheet by the original name.  Trying to find a easy solution to keeping consistency with different companies.

Comment: Please share the script you have so far with any sensitive information removed

Answer (score 0):

I changed the process of CopyTo() to another spreadsheet and then deleting the original sheet and naming the 'Copy of' back to the original sheet name.  I now CopyTo() and use the enums to update the original in the same sheet range.copyTo(orig,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT,false);
range.copyTo(orig,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA,false);
range.copyTo(orig,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION,false);
range.copyTo(orig,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING,false);
range.copyTo(orig,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);  I then delete the 'Copy of..' sheet and the references do not seem to be effected.  Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? Is it solved now?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to update a sheet that has multiple distributions copies.  However, the issues is if there are any user data entries, including Data Validations, you must save those prior to doing the CopyPaste and restore them afterwards.  All of which can be added to the script